# What is the nature of the Juni Taisen?

Tags: juuni-taisen

The contest involves twelve warriors that have some sort of power (some supernatural). Though the concept of common sense will fade away with elements like Necromantic and flying people in the show. One thing that stuck in my head was the part about the one wish to be granted to the winner.
In the end, we see the Rat warrior going through 99 wishes that most of them are impossible to grand (like gaining another superpower or world peace). So what is the nature of the contest? Who is holding these contests and what kind of power do they have to grant such wishes?